# Wordpress shortcode to pull product post data

Tags: custom-post-types, woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode, export

I am looking for a way to pull(export) product post data (WooCommerce) using a shortcode by Product post ID to another general post

(ex. product post title/string).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your functions.php file and then you can use `[product_title id="123"]` shortcode

If you want other product meta you can edit the function to return any product data you would want

```
/**
 * Product title shortcode.
 *  `[product_title id="123"]` to get a specific product title, by ID
 * 
 * @return string  The post's title.
 */
add_shortcode( 'product_title', function( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => get_the_ID(),
    ), $atts, 'post_title' );
    return get_the_title( absint( $atts['id'] ) );
});
```